# Is $E[E(X|Y)|Z] =E[X|Y,Z]$ If so, how to prove?

Tags: conditional-expectation

Does $E[E(X|Y)|Z] =E[X|Y,Z]$?  Also, what about $E[E(X|Y=y)|Z=z] =E[X|Y=y,Z=z]$   I'm confused by the relations.  It seems intuitively to be the case.   If it is correct, how do I mathematically prove it.   I've searched on this site and elsewhere...

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: No, this is not from a course or textbook.  Just trying to understand for myself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Those two conditional expectations differ in
>   general:$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X|Y)|Z] \ne\mathbb{E}[X|Y,Z]$$

As a matter of fact, strictly speaking, they do not even live in the same functional space as the first one is a function of $Z$, measurable wrt $\sigma(Z)$, the $\sigma$ algebra induced by $Z$, while the second one is a function of $(Y,Z)$, hence measurable wrt $\sigma(Y,Z)$, the $\sigma$ algebra induced by $(Y,Z)$,

As a counter-example, consider the setting when

1. $X$ and $Y$ are independent
2. $X$ and $Z$ are dependent, with $\mathbb{E}[X|Z]\ne \mathbb{E}[X]$

Then, because of the independence between $X$ and $Y$, $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)=\mathbb{E}[X]$ and therefore$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X|Y)|Z]= \mathbb{E}[X]\ne\mathbb{E}[X|Y,Z]$$

A valid equality is instead$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X|Y,Z)|Z]=\mathbb{E}[X|Z]$$that holds for all dependence relations between the three random variables.

---

**Notations:** The difference between the notations $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X|Y)|Z]$ and $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X|Y=y)|Z=z]$ is that

1. $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X|Y)|Z]$ is a random variable, transform of the random variable $Z$ (and not of the random variable $Y$ since $Y$Y is  also conditioned on $Z$);
2. $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X|Y=y)|Z=z]$ is a function of apparently both $y$ and $z$, but in fact *only* of $y$ (as explained below) ***which has no clear meaning from a probabilistic point of view***. Indeed, for a given value $y$, $\mathbb{E}(X|Y=y)$ is a constant for which taking a conditional expectation conditional on the realisation $Z=z$ makes little sense as it also returns $\mathbb{E}(X|Y=y)$. For instance, if $X$ depends on both $Y$ and $X$ as a random variable, for a given realisation $y$ of $Y$ and $Z$ of $z$, $\mathbb{E}(X|Y=y)$ is a constant that generally differs from $\mathbb{E}(X)$ and from $\mathbb{E}(X|Y=y,Z=z)$. But  $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X|Y=y)|Z=z]$ is *not* a realisation of the random variable $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X|Y)|Z]$. The ***correct realisation*** is $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X|Y)|Z=z]$

Comment: Thank you for this comment, Xi'an.   I am unclear about your response on one thing:  in your counterexample, if X and Y are independent (therefore $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)=   \mathbb{E}[X]$) and if X and Z are dependent, then why is $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X|Y)|Z]= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X)|Z]= \mathbb{E}[X]$?

Comment: ..because $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is a constant...